# How to install Liquibase in a self hosted Windows agent ? (Azure Devops Pipeline)

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, pipeline, liquibase, cd

I am creating an Azure pipeline for the first time in my life (and a pipeline too) and there are some basic concepts that I don't understand.

First of all I have trouble understanding how the installation works, if  my .yaml file installs Liquibase, will Liquibase installation run every time the pipeline is triggered? (by pushing on github)

Also, I don't know how to run liquibase commands from the agent, I see [here](https://github.com/DanZDatical/MiscExamples/blob/main/commonpipeline.yml) that they use the liquibase bat file, I guess you have to download the zip from the Liquibase website and put it in the agent, but how do you do that?

Comment: I found this article that explains how you can download and configure Liquibase in a yaml file: https://mohitgoyal.co/2019/02/24/install-and-configure-liquibase-for-database-ci-cd/

Answer (score 0):

You can setup Liquibase in a couple of different ways:

1. You can use Liquibase Docker image in your Azure pipeline. You can find more information about using Liquibase Docker image here: https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/liquibase-community/using-liquibase-and-docker.html
2. You can install Liquibase on Azure agent and ensure that all Liquibase jobs run on that specific agent where Liquibase is installed. Liquibase releases can be downloaded from: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/releases

The URL you point to shows that Liquibase commands are invoked from C:\apps\Liquibase directory.